# Creating a Subway Station Network in Python using Graph, Vertex and Edge data structure

Tags: python, graph, edges

I'm fairly new to Python and I have a college work that requires to use the graph, vertex and edge concepts, however I'm struggling on how to properly implement this.

Below is the description of the work required:

a) In Vertex, create a Station subclass, to contain the station id and the position, in decimal degrees, of the location
of the object on the earth's surface.

b) Create a list of Station objects from the dataset in lisbon.stations.csv.

c) Under Edge, create an Edge_line subclass, to contain the line that the connection is part of.

d) Create a list of "Edge_line" objects from the same data set.

e) Create a Graph structure.

f) Create a procedure/method to be able to view the network.

Example:

```
Import myplotlib.myplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.line(x,y, c=color)
```

- To view the connections where x and y are lists with the positions on the map of the end stations of an Edge; Run as many times as the number of connections.
- Encode the color as shown in the table in lisbon.lines.csv.

Below is my code at the moment. I think I managed to made it to point c), but would appreciate help on reviewing the entire code.

https://pastebin.com/5t9A8dfC

Also, please find below the CSV files required to use on this work.

**lisbon.lines.csv**

```
"line","name","colour"
1,"Vermelha","r"
2,"Azul","b"
3,"Verde","g"
4,"Amarela","y"
```

**lisbon.stations.csv**

```
"id","latitude","longitude","name"
1,38.771746,-9.1306207,"Aeroporto"
2,38.7758674,-9.1177189,"Encarnação"
3,38.775383,-9.1048967,"Moscavide"
4,38.770726,-9.1014767,"Oriente"
5,38.764569,-9.1064637,"Cabo Ruivo"
6,38.761624,-9.112163,"Olivais"
7,38.755357,-9.113954,"Chelas"
8,38.747860,-9.118439,"Bela Vista"
9,38.739911,-9.123824,"Olaias"
10,38.737158,-9.133888,"Alameda"
11,38.735426,-9.145261,"Saldanha"
12,38.734815,-9.154220,"São Sebastião"
13,38.713814,-9.122570,"Santa Apolónia"
14,38.707175,-9.133352,"Terreiro do Paço"
15,38.710700,-9.139274,"Chiado"
16,38.715169,-9.141632,"Restauradores"
17,38.720109,-9.145883,"Avenida"
18,38.725357,-9.150099,"Marquês de Pombal"
19,38.729726,-9.150335,"Parque"
20,38.737849,-9.158458,"Praça de Espanha"
21,38.742029,-9.168977,"Jardim Zoologico"
22,38.748530,-9.172462,"Laranjeiras"
24,38.749609,-9.179994,"Alto dos Moinhos"
25,38.752836,-9.189426,"Colégio Militar"
26,38.759139,-9.192718,"Carnide"
27,38.762243,-9.196849,"Pontinha"
28,38.760578,-9.204724,"Alfornelos"
29,38.758411,-9.219122,"Amadora Este"
30,38.752186,-9.224132,"Reboleira"
31,38.706116,-9.145123,"Cais do Sodré"
32,38.713994,-9.138450,"Rossio"
33,38.716256,-9.136219,"Martim Moniz"
34,38.722266,-9.135371,"Intendente"
35,38.726275,-9.134942,"Anjos"
36,38.733639,-9.134167,"Arroios"
37,38.748653,-9.141581,"Roma"
38,38.753129,-9.144016,"Alvalade"
39,38.760212,-9.157874,"Campo Grande"
40,38.760296,-9.166135,"Telheiras"
41,38.793193,-9.173379,"Odivelas"
42,38.785867,-9.172124,"Senhor Roubado"
43,38.779645,-9.159721,"Ameixoeira"
44,38.772903,-9.159753,"Lumiar"
45,38.767022,-9.155333,"Quinta das Conchas"
46,38.751812,-9.159045,"Cidade Universitária"
47,38.747001,-9.147973,"Entre Campos"
48,38.741545,-9.146739,"Campo Pequeno"
49,38.730925,-9.146653,"Picoas"
50,38.720094,-9.154077,"Rato"
23,38.742541,-9.133747,"Areeiro"
```

**lisbon.connections.csv**

```
"station1","station2","line"
1,2,1
2,3,1
3,4,1
4,5,1
5,6,1
6,7,1
7,8,1
8,9,1
9,10,1
10,11,1
11,12,1
13,14,2
14,15,2
15,16,2
16,17,2
17,18,2
18,19,2
19,12,2
12,20,2
20,21,2
21,22,2
22,24,2
24,25,2
25,26,2
26,27,2
27,28,2
28,29,2
29,30,2
31,15,3
15,32,3
32,33,3
33,34,3
34,35,3
35,36,3
36,10,3
10,23,3
23,37,3
37,38,3
38,39,3
39,40,3
41,42,4
42,43,4
43,44,4
44,45,4
45,39,4
39,46,4
46,47,4
47,48,4
48,11,4
11,49,4
49,18,4
18,50,4
```

PS: Let me know if there is any other way to attach the actual csv files to this thread.

Comment: Welcome Tiago! If you'd like a general review, this question might be more suited to the codereview stackexchange. If you want help with the problem you mention in the comment, it might be more appropriate to edit your question and trim down the problem to the part you're having trouble with

Comment: Hello loopbackbee, thank you for the comment. It's my very first post here in stack overflow, I will try trimming it down a bit more. But like I mentioned on my previous comment, I'm stuck on point c), since I need to to contain the line that the connection is part of.